# numpy.argsort is giving me strange unordered ints instead of sorted floats

Tags: arrays, sorting, numpy, stack

I have two arrays of the same size and am multiplying one column by another to an output array using

```
array3=[]  
for x in range(0,array1,shape[0]):  
    array3.append(array1[x,5]/array2[x,5])   
array_stack=np.hstack(array3).tolist()  
array_sort=np.argsort(array_stack)
```

`array_stack` gives me a list of size 410 of float values between 1
and 2 which is what I want (1.2,1.5, etc.)  `array_sort` gives me a
list/array? of size (410,) of ints with values like 402, 75,
etc. (nothing like the floats it should be sorting and also not in any
sorted order)

I've tried replacing `np.argsort` with `.sort()` and get the same
output issues

Thoughts?

Comment: changing np.argsort to just np.sort fixed the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`np.argsort` documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) states that the function

> Returns the indices that would sort an array.

Hence what you see  means that the smallest element of `array_stack` is `array_stack[402]`, the second smallest is `array_stack[75]` etc.

Comment: ahhhhh, that explains the seemingly unordered random numbers!  Thanks!